# How can we see the create password page in Magento2 directly?

Tags: magento2

How can I access the Create Password page in my local environment? The email functionality is not setup in my local so I couldn't access the page through browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to the page:
/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/CreatePassword.php

Change execute() function as below:

```
public function execute()
    {
        $resetPasswordToken = (string)$this->getRequest()->getParam('token');
        $customerId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
                  $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('resetPassword')->setCustomerId($customerId)
                    ->setResetPasswordLinkToken($resetPasswordToken);
                return $resultPage;


    }
```

Now access the page directly in your browser by adding an existing customer id as below:

```
<website_name>/customer/account/createPassword/?id=<customer_id>&token=8ebf7486db44b57de5cafc308c6802b4
```